# First step Arduino Uno R3?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I won the arduino uno r3 in an event, but I have doubts about how to take the first steps to learn how to program it. I would like to understand which courses I am looking for that work for my arduino model (uno r3) and which programming languages and which IDEs I can use. So I can look for a course in Udemy or another platform that I can learn without having to buy an arduino of another brand

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only language you really need to know to code an Arduino is C++. Even with just the basics, you can do quite a lot. These are some things I think are a must to know:

- Variables
- If Statments
- Loops
- Importing Classes
- Calling Functions

Next you can download the [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software), and start coding. Look up tutorials on YouTube to get a hand of the different commands you have at your finger tips and how to compile and upload your code to the board. You'll be using different functions such as `digitalWrite()` which can be used to turn an LED connected to a certain pin on or off, and many more.

In short, learn C++, and look up YouTube tutorials and you should be good.

Although you won't need to take classes for the programming side, you may need to take some when creating circuits with the Arduino. Electronics can be hard to learn, and some people may need some resource other than YouTube to learn that.